# PHP curl_exec returns "413 Request Entity" error if IFNULL function is used in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I am calling a curl function to get some html code. This code works fine with COALESCE but returns "413 request entity error if i use IFNULL in query data ! I am puzzled. Any idea?
code is:

```
    $form_specs = [
                'form_type' => 'report_html_table',
                'query' => 'SELECT bvr_no,date,veh.short_name vehicle_name, from_date,upto_date,drivers.name driver_name, drivers2.name driver2_name,
                            cleaners.name cleaner_name, branches.name branch_name,(case when IFNULL(vr_amt,0) > 0 then "PAYABLE" else "RECEIVABLE" end) pay_type,
                            (case when IFNULL(vr_amt,0) > 0 then IFNULL(vr_amt,0) else 0 end) to_pay_amt,
                            (case when IFNULL(vr_amt,0) > 0 then 0 else abs(IFNULL(vr_amt,0)) end) to_rec_amt,
                            br.*
                            FROM tblbh_reg br
                            left outer join tblmainmaster veh on veh.code = br.vehicle
                            left outer join tblmainmaster drivers on drivers.code = br.driver
                            left outer join tblmainmaster drivers2 on drivers2.code = br.driver2
                            left outer join tblmainmaster cleaners on cleaners.code = br.cleaner
                            left outer join tblmainmaster branches on branches.code = br.branch
                            where_criteria order by bvr_no'
            ];

$data = array("form_specs" => $form_specs);

$ch = curl_init();
if ($con_generate_form_library == "local") {
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/VsoftLibrary1.0/generate_report_library.php");
} else {
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.weforweb.in/VsoftLibrary1.0/generate_report_library.php");
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$form_html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What does the result of the query look like in either case?

Comment: I am just passing a query string as json data and curl gets me back some html code.

Comment: Then it's up to you to do some debugging and discover what happens when you execute the query on your mysql server.